# TortoiseHG doesn't show up in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, mercurial

TortoiseHG previously worked on 12.10, but after today's reinstall, it simply doesn't show up, not even with the `thg` command.

Comment: I have the same behavior; moreover, the returned code from thg is 0, which does not help much :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to install it rather easily by using the tortoisehg ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mercurial tortoisehg
```

Note: @piwi's method works too.

Comment: thanks, I couldn't figure out why my thg showed no vital signs today.. this put the wheels back on my car

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but rather a workaround. The version of TortoiseHG from the repository works fine.

I first installed the latest version of mercurial (otherwise thg will complain about a version mismatch for hg); I installed it in `~/opt`:

```
hg clone --branch stable http://selenic.com/hg ~/thg/mercurial
cd ~/thg/mercurial
python setup.py install --prefix=$HOME/opt

export PATH="$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

I use `bash`, so I needed to remove the [hash entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) for mercurial:

```
hash -d hg
```

Then I made a copy of the thg repository and ran it from the repository I wanted to work from:

```
hg clone --branch stable http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg ~/thg/tortoisehg
cd ~/devel/myrepo
~/thg/tortoisehg/thg
```

Comment: Although this worked as expected, I found a PPA that works. See my answer.